# How should I format a SD Card for Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ41?

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

I just formatted a SD-Card which was in use with the Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ41 for quite a while. Now it is not working. Always when I insert it, it tells me to re-insert the SD-Card ("SD-Karte erneut einsetzen").

It is a 64 GB class-10 card which already worked. I thought It was FAT-32 formatted, but when I do so it doesn't work. I use gparted and 1MB "free preceeding space".

On my laptop, the card works fine.

Comment: I suggest that you let the Panasonic Lumix format it. It should know how to format it.

Comment: I see. Well, maybe there should be the `exFAT` file system (not FAT32). You can use Windows to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reapeatedly inserting it helped. After ~5 times the camera offered to format the card.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── DCIM
│   └── 109_PANA
│       └── P1090748.JPG
├── MISC
└── PRIVATE
    ├── AVCHD
    │   ├── AVCHDTN
    │   │   ├── THUMB.TDT
    │   │   └── THUMB.TID
    │   └── BDMV
    │       ├── CLIPINF
    │       ├── INDEX.BDM
    │       ├── MOVIEOBJ.BDM
    │       ├── PLAYLIST
    │       └── STREAM
    └── FILEMNG.DAT
```

It is formatted with exfat. 16.00 MiB at the beginning are not allocated.